# How do I pass a dictionary in alamofire multipart data? iOS swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift3.2

I want to make a dictionary and pass these data along with a video file upload using alamofire. Below is my json.

```
{
    "taskid": "2",
    "task_type": "N\/A",
    "fileName": null,
    “videofile”:
    "task": [
        {
            “Cid": 1,
            “Start”: "00:00:00",
            “End”: "00:00:00"
        },

        {
            “Cid": 2,
            “Start”: "00:00:00",
            “End”: "00:00:00"
        },
        {
           “Cid": 3,
            “Start”: "00:00:00",
            “End”: "00:00:00"
        },
    ]
}
```

what should be my code for the below dictionary array?
how to pass?

```
multipartFormData.append((self.singleTonFile?.fileUrl)! , withName: "videofile" , fileName: fileNameOnly + ".webm", mimeType: "video/webm")
multipartFormData.append(self.singleTon.userid.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "userid")

multipartFormData.append(self.singleTon.taskid.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "taskid")

multipartFormData.append(self.singleTon. filename.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "filename")
```

@riddhi . - chk the solution of one of my sample. This is a different format. but follows array of dictionary as parameter..

```
for i in 0..<self.singleTon.individualTask.count
        {
            let dictTask = ["id":self.singleTon.individualTask[i],
                        "start_time":self.singleTon.individualTaskStartTime[i],
                        "end_time":self.singleTon.individualTaskEndTime[i],
                        ]
            parameters.append(dictTask as [String : AnyObject])
        }
           ]
        var dataParameters = Data()
        do
        {
            dataParameters = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let objectString = String(data: dataParameters, encoding: .utf8)

            print("objectString : ", objectString!)
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        var alamoDict = [String: Any]()
        if let scrn: NSScreen = NSScreen.main() {
            let rect: NSRect = scrn.frame
            let height = rect.size.height
            let width = rect.size.width
            self.singleTon.display = "\(height)" + "X" + "\(width)"
        }
         print("self.singleTon.processor  ", self.singleTon.processor)
            print("resolution  ", self.singleTon.display)
        alamoDict = ["task":parameters,
                         "userid":self.singleTon.userId,
                         "video_duration":self.singleTon.video_duration,
                         "fileName":self.singleTon.fileNameForUpload,
                         "User_type":self.singleTon.User_type,
                         "OS":self.singleTon.OS,
                         "processor":self.singleTon.processor,
                         "task_type":self.singleTon.task_type,
                         "taskid":self.singleTon.taskIdPassed,
                         "memory":self.singleTon.memory,
                         "Freememory":self.singleTon.freememory,
                         "display":self.singleTon.display,
                         ]

        var dataAlamoDict = Data()
```

// this is for testing json serialisation

```
    *

do
        {
            dataAlamoDict = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: alamoDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))//NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: nil, error: nil)
            let objectString = String(data: dataParameters, encoding: .utf8)

            print("objectString : ", objectString!)
        }

   //This is ur alamofire format


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(dataAlamoDict, withName: "TaskInfo")
        //  …… etc ec*
```

*

Comment: please try with my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070724/6193340

Comment: @starterMac Have you got solution?

Comment: @riddhi i followed above solution by bhavik .. it worked

Comment: how to send task parameter which is array of dictionary ?

Comment: @riddhi -ok i will edit my question with answer.. check above

Answer (score 3):

for helping people like riddhi

@riddhi . - chk the solution of one of my sample. This is a different format. but follows array of dictionary as parameter..

```
for i in 0..<self.singleTon.individualTask.count
        {
            let dictTask = ["id":self.singleTon.individualTask[i],
                        "start_time":self.singleTon.individualTaskStartTime[i],
                        "end_time":self.singleTon.individualTaskEndTime[i],
                        ]
            parameters.append(dictTask as [String : AnyObject])
        }
           ]
        var dataParameters = Data()
        do
        {
            dataParameters = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let objectString = String(data: dataParameters, encoding: .utf8)

            print("objectString : ", objectString!)
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        var alamoDict = [String: Any]()
        if let scrn: NSScreen = NSScreen.main() {
            let rect: NSRect = scrn.frame
            let height = rect.size.height
            let width = rect.size.width
            self.singleTon.display = "\(height)" + "X" + "\(width)"
        }
         print("self.singleTon.processor  ", self.singleTon.processor)
            print("resolution  ", self.singleTon.display)
        alamoDict = ["task":parameters,
                         "userid":self.singleTon.userId,
                         "video_duration":self.singleTon.video_duration,
                         "fileName":self.singleTon.fileNameForUpload,
                         "User_type":self.singleTon.User_type,
                         "OS":self.singleTon.OS,
                         "processor":self.singleTon.processor,
                         "task_type":self.singleTon.task_type,
                         "taskid":self.singleTon.taskIdPassed,
                         "memory":self.singleTon.memory,
                         "Freememory":self.singleTon.freememory,
                         "display":self.singleTon.display,
                         ]

        var dataAlamoDict = Data()
```

// this is for testing json serialisation format

```
    *

do
        {
            dataAlamoDict = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: alamoDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))//NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: nil, error: nil)
            let objectString = String(data: dataParameters, encoding: .utf8)

            print("objectString : ", objectString!)
        }

   //This is ur alamofire format


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(dataAlamoDict, withName: "TaskInfo")
        //  …… etc ec* type ur rest of the code
```

*