# Uploading text file using Alamofire

Tags: ios, upload, swift4, alamofire, multipart

I have a text file saved in a directory inside the document directory
I want to upload this file to stream (upload) to the server using Alamofire but I'm getting an error and I don't follow what is the error mean
the response should be a string, the problem isn't in the format of the response data even if I used responseString I'm getting an error.

This my code:

```
 let folder = getFolder()

    let textFile = fileUrl?.appendingPathComponent(fileTemp)

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]

        let finalUrl = url + "/myMethod"

    Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(textFile!, withName: "file")

    },
    to: finalUrl,headers:headers,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
    upload.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
    }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
    print(encodingError)
    }})
```

And this is the response value I am getting:

> Status Code: 400, Headers {
>       "Cache-Control" =     (
>           private
>       );
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           1647
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "text/html"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Thu, 06 Sep 2018 09:32:47 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
>       );
>       "X-AspNet-Version" =     (
>           "4.0.30319"
>       );
>       "X-Powered-By" =     (
>           "ASP.NET"
>       ); } } [Data]: 1647 bytes [Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}))

Does anyone have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa error 3840 using JSON (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171111/cocoa-error-3840-using-json-ios)

Comment: I saw this post before and it didn't help

Comment: can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070571/alamofire-multipartformdata-use-urlrequest/45070781#45070781

Comment: I tried it and  got the same error

Comment: try with POSTMAN and verify API is working properly

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the upload format is text

**Change this:**

```
multipartFormData.append(textFile!, withName: "file")
```

**To this:**

```
multipartFormData.append(textFile!, withName: "file", fileName: filename, mimeType: "text/plain")
```